# Nodejs crashes when source code is edited live, how to stop this behaviour

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm new to nodejs and reactjs. While I have a server running ok, there is an unwanted behaviour which means that node (or npm) is watching the source file for changes. However, this is not useful as node then focuses on the autosaved file that is prepended with the '#' symbol. The prevents the server from then being restarted again. If I remember to stop the server before editing the file then there is no problem, but that is not a workflow I am used to. With a django server, you can edit the file and then on saving the file, the server will restart and either show your work or spit out a useful error. Is there a way to stop this live editing behaviour please.

Here is package.json file, is it possible a setting in here that is facilitating the unwanted live editing.

```
{
  "name": "my-app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: If you can provide some commands about node watching, perhaps your package.json and commands will help me to understand what you are really saying because I can't comprehend what you are saying

Comment: Nodejs is restarting the server when the source file is being edited. If it must restart itself, I only want it to do that once I have saved the file not when starting to type. I have not customised node or react in anyway, it's currently out of the box configuration on Linux Mint. Will try to add package.json in post for you to look at

Comment: Right apologies. It is an emacs issue, I closed emacs and opened the source code in text edit and had no problems. @SkrewEverything, if you would kindly changed your comment to a solution, I will mark it as the answer, as it's your comment that made me question my text editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the server only restarts when you save the file. Until you save the edited file to the filesystem, the server doesn't know that you are changing something because the watcher can't see what you are doing.

Once you save the file to the disk, the watcher recognizes something has changed and tries to restart the server. Maybe just restart your computer(the problem might be other programs) because I have never seen this type of behavior in my experience.

If it still continues, maybe you need to file a bug report in the `create-react-app`(I guess this is what you are using) repo.

Answer (score 0):

The issues has nothing to do with Node / React what is happening there is you have enabled **autosave** for your vscode so each and every line that you write is being autosaved noting that will yield errors not because you caused it but due to file being save without you being even done doing what you wanted to do.

**Solution**

Switch off autosave within your VSCode

Comment: Vscode or not even with atom or sublime you can set autosave, so concept  is the same

Comment: One can comment when they 50xp last time I checked  so yea.

Comment: I understand what you saying and I will definitely try to make my answers more clear and avoid assumptions, thanks for the tip

Comment: Actually, @NtshemboHlongwane is correct with his answer, just wrong editor. I am using emacs, however, trying to figure out what is causing perpetual autosave on every keystroke is beyond me, so I am now tryin VSCode, but I hate it with a passion because it's even harder to configure than Emacs, but from an editing point of view, it's easier for javascript.